# how to switch around two spans with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have 11 dt's generated by a php script to which I have no access. Example below.

```
<dt>
<span class="Required FormFieldRequired" style="visibility: visible">*</span> 
    <span class="FormFieldLabel">Email Address:</span>
</dt>
```

I need the Required span and all its contents to *follow* the FormFieldLabel span.
The Required span text never changes, the label content does change.

`$('span.FormFieldLabel').insertBefore( 'span.Required.FormFieldRequired' );` does not work, it repeats everything and messes up the form.

Reading has suggested usage of the text() function but not how I should apply it.

I basically want to change 'A before B' to become 'B before A'.

Answer (score 3):

i assume you have multiple `dt` where you want to do this. so you need to do this:

```
$('span.FormFieldLabel').each(function() {
    $(this).insertBefore( $(this).closest('dt').find('span.Required.FormFieldRequired') );
});
```

Comment: +1. this is the correct answer, assuming your assumption is correct. but based on his HTML, the argument to `insertBefore()` could be much simpler.

Comment: No, it's the right answer; the OP states that there are 11 `<dt>` in his disposal - and that's actually the problem here, as simple `remove`-`append` will just group all the labels in a single place. As a sidenote, I shouldn't have spent so much time preparing the demo. )

Comment: @raina77ow i haven't seen the disposal :/ ... and sorry for not preparing a demo. gave you a +1 ;)

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$('span.FormFieldLabel').each(function() {
  $(this).insertBefore($(this).prev());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VUhsu/).

Answer (score 0):

Does this get you what you want?

```
$('.Required').remove().insertAfter('.FormFieldLabel')
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/V6HQb/

Answer (score 0):

```
var html = '<span class="Required FormFieldRequired" style="visibility: visible">*      </span>';
$("Required").remove();
$(dt).append(html);
```